# Access 2016 - Showing a report on a form based on text box parameter

Tags: ms-access

To start, I have a report that shows yearly sales figures - which is based of a query. When you open the report you are asked for the year, which is as intended.

Now I'd like to have a form that has a subreport, ie showing you the sales report of a year. I've dragged the report into the form and that works - however when you open the form it asks for the parameter. Instead of this I'd like a text box on the form that you input the year which then loads the report.

How would I approach this?

Comment: You can refer to a form control in your query using the syntax [Forms]![YourFormName]!{TheControlName]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow morning. Thanks for the heads up though!